# Decoding Json to get string value

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to get string value in a json but I keep getting nil.

This is json structure

```
{
    "user": {
        "password": "...",
        "name": "...",
        "authToken": "...",
        "events": [
            {
                "uuid": (int)
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

this is how I am decoding.

```
do {
       let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options:[]) as! [String : Any?]

       let authToken: String = json["authToken"] as! String

       print(authToken)

   } catch let error {
       print(error)
   }
```

but I keep getting nil value in my console

Comment: try json["user"]["authToken"]

Comment: @toto this is not swiftyJSON so that would not work

Comment: Use `Codable` and `JSONDecoder`. Do not use the legacy `JSONSerialization` and force casting. In any case, you need to decode several levels, you cannot just access `authToken`, which is nested inside the `user` Dictionary of the JSON.

Comment: As pointed by others, your top-level key on your json object is "user".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
let user = json["user"] as! [String:Any] 
let authToken = user["authToken"] as! String
```

Answer (score 0):

Create this Object model:

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Matrix
struct Matrix: Codable {
    let user: User
}

// MARK: - User
struct User: Codable {
    let password, name, authToken: String
    let events: [Event]
}

// MARK: - Event
struct Event: Codable {
   let uuid: Int
}
```

Use it like this:

```
do {
    let matrix = try JSONDecoder().decode(Matrix.self, from: jsonData)
    let token = matrix.user.authToken
} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

replace Matrix with your desire object name

Comment: Don't use `try?` to mask errors. Use `try` inside a `do-catch` block.

Comment: updated my answer, though is obvious that it should use the safest way

Answer (score 0):

You can access authToken using chaining transformations like this:

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options:[]) as? [String : Any]

let authToken = json
    .flatMap { $0["user"] as? [String: Any] }
    .flatMap { $0["authToken"] as? String }
```

In the end, you will have an optional authToken property. If JSON is valid and authToken exists, you can unwrap it and reach the value!

Comment: Don't use `flatMap` with `Optional` values, that's deprecated already. Moreover, using `flatMap` or `compactMap` to get the value of a single key from a `Dictionary` is a really bad idea - and your current implementation won't even work, since that `flatMap` would iterate over all key-value pairs of the `Dictionary`.

Comment: Hello! Function .flatMap is deprecated on Array (now you should use .compactMap), but not Optional type. Using Codable protocol is a better idea, I know. But in this case - just for testing, why we can't use provided answer?

Comment: I think you've missed, that in my case, .flatMap acts on Optional type, but not on Dictionary. It will not iterate through the collection, it will just perform the transformation, in case the value is not nil.